# How can I set default values for background-color and border css with Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have some inputs which I modify their css with `Jquery` and I want to get their default css. I know that a method exists in Jquery to change the css (.css) and the property `initial` uses to make your html element show as default so according to [their examples](http://api.jquery.com/css/) I wrote the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var styles= {
         border : "initial",
         backgroundColor: "initial"
     };

     $('#code').css(styles);
});
```

but neither `border` or `backgroundColor` changes their values to their default `css` values.

Am I missing something? It is another property like `initial` to get their default css values for `border` and `background-color`?

**EDIT:** Here it is the HTML related with that input.

```
<input id = 'code' type='text' value = 'Prove' style = 'border: 0px; background-color: transparent;'/>
```

**EDIT2:** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/goe989hs/5/) it is the jsfiddle in which you can see how I want the input (code2) and how the input it is being shown (code1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do u mean by default values

Comment: Can you include `html` , `css` at Question ? Is expected result to toggle element `css` ?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal The values of css that an input have by default. I mean, with border and background-color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     var styles= {
         border : "inherit",
         backgroundColor: "inherit"
     };

     $('#code').css(styles);
});
</script>
```

just change initial to inherit

Answer (score 1):

To remove all styles from the element and follow defaults.

```
$('#code').removeAttr('style');
```

To remove specific property from style

```
$('#code').css("background-color", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Accordingly to W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp) the **initial** keyword can be used for any CSS property, and on any HTML element.

I didn't find anything wrong with your code. See a working demo here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var styles= {
         border : "initial",
         backgroundColor: "initial"
     };

     $('#code').css(styles);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/goe989hs/1/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put my HTML code before. Here it is the good update jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/goe989hs/5/ with inputs. Here you can see how I want the input (code2) and how the input it is being shown (code1).

Answer (score 0):

```
 border : "initial",
```

The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value. Check Your defaults. otherwise code is working - http://plnkr.co/edit/6erExH5JjMFKb0J9y61n?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a new `input` element , set `id` , `value` and other attributes values to `#code` attribute values, use `.replaceWith()` to replace existing `#code` element with created `input` element having default styles

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var code = $("#code");
  var input = $("<input>", {
    id: code.attr("id"),
    attr: {
      "value": code.val()
    }
  })
  $("#code").replaceWith(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="code" value="Prove" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px" />
<input id="code2" value="Prove" />
```